# Guzzle version conflict with Facebook/Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.4, facebook

I want to update Magento 2.4.3 (also 2.4.3-p1/p2) to 2.4.4.

We have the module facebook/facebook-for-magento2 installed, but this requires facebook/php-business-sdk 9.0.3. Version 9.0.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5 || ^7.0.

Magento 2.4.4 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.2]

So I have a conflict where they each require a different version. Is there any solution to this that doesn't involve removing the facebook module?

Answer (score 0):

Locally I am running 2.4.4, I just ran `composer require facebook/facebook-for-magento2` and it installed fine, so think something else may be the issue?

My current dependancies:

```
astock/stock-api-libphp                        1.1.5     requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (~7.3)                      
aws/aws-sdk-php                                3.222.10  requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (^5.3.3 || ^6.2.1 || ^7.0)  
facebook/php-business-sdk                      9.0.3     requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (^6.5 || ^7.0)              
magento/framework                              103.0.4   requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.3.0)                    
magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework  3.9.0     requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.3.0)                    
magento/product-community-edition              2.4.4     requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.3.0)                    
magento/product-enterprise-edition             2.4.4     requires  guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.3.0)
```

My version of `guzzlehttp/guzzle` is `7.4.2` which matches both Magento's requirement for ^7.3.0 ([https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/^7.3.0/7.4.2](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/%5E7.3.0/7.4.2)) and the Facebook SDK ^6.5 || ^7.0 ([https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/^6.5%20||%20^7.0/7.4.2](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/%5E6.5%20%7C%7C%20%5E7.0/7.4.2))

To diagnose this run `composer why-not guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.4.2` which should print out a list of incompatible packages.